# Loop call api and display the correct value in its display order with Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

-Assume have list of student

-click `onCheck` 1 time will **loop** through `arrSubject`  , `arrSubject` have 4 element and call api 4 time to get point of the student. (this is the data requested from the back-end so it must be called like that)

-in the component `Student` have table to show list of point base on `arrSubject`

when data return i want to display in correct order of table

*The issue is i call api in order like `["math", "history", "physics", "chemistry"]`, i display
the same in column table , but the return value is unordered `["history", "math", "chemistry", "physics"]` . It will cause the displayed data to be wrong

```
const arrSubject = ["math", "history", "physics", "chemistry"];
// Teacher
const Teacher = () => {
  const onCheck = (id) => {
    for (let name of arrSubject) {
      dispatch(handleCheck({ id, name }));
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      {/* let's say it's a list and there are many student to click */}
      <button onClick={onCheck}>Check point Student</button>
      <Student />
    </>
  );
};
export default Teacher;

// Student
const Student = () => {
  const { point } = useSelect((state) => state.checkSlice);
  //The point here corresponds to each subject returned
  let originData = [];
  arrSubject.map((subject, index) => {
    originData.push({ name: subject, point });
  });

  const columns = [...]

  return (
    <Table
      bordered
      dataSource={originData ? originData : []}
      columns={columns}
    />
  );
};

// Thunk
export const handleCheck = createAsyncThunk("check", async (data) => {
  try {
    const response = await checkAPI.checkPoint(data);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    return data;
  }
});

// Slice
const checkSlice = createSlice({
  name: "check",
  initialState: {
    point: {},
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(handleCheck.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
      state.point = payload;
    });
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the returned data from the API depending upon the order of subject !

For Example :-

```js
const arrSubject = ["math", "history", "physics", "chemistry"];
// Teacher
const Teacher = () => {
  const onCheck = (id) => {
    for (let name of arrSubject) {
      dispatch(handleCheck({ id, name }));
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      {/* let's say it's a list and there are many student to click */}
      <button onClick={onCheck}>Check point Student</button>
      <Student />
    </>
  );
};
export default Teacher;

// Student
const Student = () => {
  const { point } = useSelect((state) => state.checkSlice);
  //The point here corresponds to each subject returned
  let originData = [];
  arrSubject.map((subject, index) => {
    originData.push({ name: subject, point });
  });

    // sort the data upon your subject name

    const orderMap = {
      math: 1,
      history: 2,
      chemistry: 3,
      physics: 4,
    };

    originData = originData.sort(
      (a, b) => orderMap[a.name] - orderMap[b.name]
    );

    console.log(originData);

  const columns = [...]

  return (
    <Table
      bordered
      dataSource={originData ? originData : []}
      columns={columns}
    />
  );
};

// Thunk
export const handleCheck = createAsyncThunk("check", async (data) => {
  try {
    const response = await checkAPI.checkPoint(data);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    return data;
  }
});

// Slice
const checkSlice = createSlice({
  name: "check",
  initialState: {
    point: {},
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(handleCheck.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
      state.point = payload;
    });
  },
});
```

Comment: data of `point` is object not array, and when everytime `point` update new data in `store` it will re-render component `Student` , it lead to `originData` just have 1 `point` of element

Comment: can you share the data of `originData` here. Sorting originData may fix your issue.